# How to update the state after refresh the App - React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm development some login screen with a simple Welcome screen,
but I have some issue with the state when refreshing the app it's still in the splash screen [**Indicator**] not separate,
 I need when I'm removing the storage key update the state loading into another status but it doesn't work with me :L, can you help me about this issue?

### myScreens

**After first Login**

[image: after Login]

**When refreshing the app [double R key] - I need moving me to the Login form**

[image]

this my Code

#### /Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage
} from "react-native";
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      isLoad: false
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("@myApp:username").then(username => {
      if (!username || username === "") {
        this.setState({
          isLoad: true
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ username: username });
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
      }
    });
  }

  _onLogin = () => {
    let { username, password } = this.state;

    if (username !== "" && password !== "") {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("@myApp:username", this.state.username).then(
        username => {
          this.setState({ username: username });
        }
      );
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    }
  };
  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoad) {
      return (
         <View
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
    >
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />
    </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="#333" barStyle="light-content" />
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 28, margin: 10 }}>Login</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Username"
            onChangeText={username => {
              this.setState({ username: username });
            }}
            value={this.state.username}
            autoCorrect={false}
            returnKeyType="next"
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              margin: 15,
              borderBottomColor: "#333",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              width: "80%"
            }}
            editable={true}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            onChangeText={password => {
              this.setState({ password: password });
            }}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            value={this.state.password}
            autoCorrect={false}
            returnKeyType="next"
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              margin: 15,
              borderBottomColor: "#333",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              width: "80%"
            }}
            editable={true}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              margin: 20,
              padding: 10,
              width: "70%",
              backgroundColor: "#1a73e8"
            }}
            onPress={this._onLogin}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", textAlign: "center", fontSize: 18 }}>
              Log In
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  }
});
```

#### ./Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  Alert,
  Text,
  AsyncStorage,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@myApp:username");
      this.setState({ name: storedValue });
      if (storedValue == null) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Error", "There was an error.");
    }
  }
  _onLogout = () => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("@myApp:username").then(() => {
      this.setState({ name: "" });
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("./assets/bg1.jpg")}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                alignSelf: "center",
                backgroundColor: "#000fff",
                padding: 10,
                color: "#fff"
              }}
            >
              {`Hello, ${this.state.name} `}
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                margin: 20,
                padding: 10,
                width: "50%",
                backgroundColor: "#1a73e8",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignSelf: "center"
              }}
              onPress={this._onLogout}
            >
              <Text
                style={{ color: "#FFF", textAlign: "center", fontSize: 18 }}
              >
                Log out?
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `componentWillMount`

```
  async componentWillMount() {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("@myApp:username").then(username => {
      if (!username || username === "") {
        this.setState({
          isLoad: true // This is the issue
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ username: username });
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
      }
    });
  }
```

First of all, you should avoid using `componentWillMount` and use `componentDidMount` as the former is now deprecated, and is not advised to use in the newer versions of react.

The problem is, when you navigate to the home screen after logging out, you are checking for `username` in the `AsyncStorage` but if its undefined, you're setting the `isLoad` state to true, which renders the `ActivityIndicator`. You should be doing `isLoad` before the promise is resolved if anything. If you replace your code with:

```
 componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({ isLoad: true });
   AsyncStorage.getItem("@myApp:username").then(username => {
      if (!username || username === "") {
        this.setState({
          isLoad: false // change this to False
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ username: username, isLoad: false });
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
      }
    });
  }
```

You should be able to see a login Screen instead of the spinner. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you but I see a login Screen instead of the spinner at the first thing before login